# Винительный или родительный падеж в отрицательной форме

Tags: грамматика, падежи

В предложении "Я читаю книги" слово"книги" стоит в винительном падеже.Но в отрицательных предложениях часто встречается родительный ("Я не читаю книг").Является ли это явление нормой или же независимо от отрицательной частицы падеж должен оставаться прежним, то есть винительным?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Родительный при отрицании – это не ошибка. Но называть всеобщей нормой я бы не стал.
Тут все упирается в ряд условий.

Во-первых, о каком глаголе идеть речь. Есть целый ряд глаголов, которые разделяют родительный и винительный падеж прямого дополнения по смысловому признаку (это в первую очередь глаголы так называемой  "ждательной" группы: "я жду трамвай" и "я жду трамвая" имеют разный смысл). Это различие сохранится и при отрицании.

И во-вторых, часто грамматика диктуется смыслом уже самого отрицания. У Пушкина в черновиках есть ответ критику, который заподозрил ошибку в строке поэта "Два века ссорить не хочу" (здесь корректно употреблен винительный). Вот ответ:

> Что гласит грамматика? Что действительный глагол, управляемый
> отрицательною частицею, требует уже не винительного, а родительного
> падежа. Например: я *не* пишу *стихов*. Но в моем стихе глагол ссорить
> управляем не частицею *не*, а глаголом *хочу*. Ergo правило сюда нейдет.
> Возьмем, например, следующее предложение: Я *не* могу вам позволить
> начать писать... *стихи*, а уж конечно не *стихов*. Неужто электрическая
> сила отрицательной частицы должна пройти сквозь всю эту цепь глаголов
> и отозваться в существительном? Не думаю.

(Ссылку не даю, все ведут на гугл-книги, а они ужасно нефункциональны для цитирования. Но поиском найдете легко.)

Это хороший пример того, как надо аккуратно подходить ко всякого рода "нормам".

И вот более полное (хотя и далеко не исчерпывающее) изложение всего вопроса:
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Comment: "Ссылку не даю" — так по вашей ссылке оно же есть

Answer (score 0):

Это является нормой. Но и винительный падеж может использоваться. Но стилистика разная.

Родительный падеж - для общего факта:
*Я не читаю книг [вообще].

Я не читал таких книг [вообще].* || При прошедшем времени падеж лучше звучит.

Винительный - если имеется в виду что-то более конкретное:
*Я не читал книги на прошлой неделе.

Я не читаю книги про приведений.*