# Предлог "из" или "с/со": информация из/со справочника

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

В комментариях к [этому вопросу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457340/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5) oleedd употребил выражение *информация **со** справочника.* Я его стал уверять, что правильно сказать ***из*** справочника, однако он возразил, что *"информация из справочника" звучит слишком научно и официально. **А вы как считаете?***

Я сам против заумных и формальных канцелярских фраз, но в данном случае считаю предлог *"из"* единственно правильным, а *"со"* допустимым только как просторечный вариант из того же ряда, что и его употребление с городами, характерное для провинциалов:

> *— А откуда ты?
>
>   — Да все мы с Рязани.*

Не стал бы задавать этот вопрос, если бы oleedd так уверенно не отстаивал своей точки зрения.

Comment: Думаю, что верно только "свою точку зрения". Не со всеми глаголами может употребляться родительный.

Comment: @oleedd: дело в том, что тут отрицание.

Comment: Не-не-не. Не всегда с отрицанием родительный падеж (хотя часто). И используется он, когда нет конкретики. Слово "своя" - это уже конкретика. Но тут и без него не звучит. Отстаивают что-то конкретное, а не в общем. *Он не отстаивал никаких принципов.* Но: *Он не отстаивал свою позицию.*

Comment: @oleedd: и всё же родительный падеж допустим и в этом случае. По крайней мере раньше так часто говорили. А я во многом консервативен.

Comment: "не отстаивал своей точки зрения" — звучит очень плохо. Вот тут прочитайте ответ бегемотуса. Весь смысл в первом абзаце: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457264/Винительный-или-родительный-падеж-в-отрицательной-форме

Comment: А по-моему, нормально. Но *не могу вам позволить начать писать стихи* действительно единственно правильно.

Comment: А вы это читали? Тут, конечно, далеко не всё. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Comment: Решающим фактором является конкретика: *Не заметил [никакой] ошибки. Не заметил [какую-то] ошибку.*

Comment: И всё-таки так тоже допустимо. Раньше так говорили. Но, если хотите, я изменю ради вас.)

Comment: Мне оно совсем не видится допустимым. Я такого не слышал. Мне без разницы, измените или нет — это не особо на что-то влияет. Я ведь и сам могу исправить) Важнее истина.

Comment: Вот в Нацкорпусе "слушался папы и целых шести мам" без отрицания: http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8B. Хоть это и тогда был не единственный вариант, но он встречался. А в моём примере, насколько я понимаю, всё же чаще употребляли родительный падеж в XIX веке и раньше, да и, возможно, в начале XX тоже чаще.

Comment: Тут играет роль слово "шесть". Как-то плохо звучит "*слушался целых шесть*". Даже вот "*слушался целых шесть начальников*" - нужен родительный. Другое дело "слушал": *Слушал целых шесть лекторов.*

Comment: Но "папа-то" просто, без числительного.

Comment: Нельзя же одно так, другое так. Выбирается один более оптимальный падеж.

Comment: Я бы написал *-то* после кавычек, раз в тексте его нет: *"слово"-то*. Кавычки - это некоторое цитирование слова. У вас, "как всегда", интересный случай.

Comment: Я встречал и другие примеры без числительных и других слов. Не могу только вспомнить конкретно. Я тоже, когда писал, задумался, правильно ли внутри кавычек, но возможности долго рассуждать не было. Вот вам и подходящий случай для вопроса. ;)

Comment: Подходящий случай, но я не стану считать иначе, даже если будет правило, что нужно писать внутри. Здравый смысл и логика превыше всего. (Правила Розенталя очень логичны. Их приятно читать.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **информация из справочника.** Других вариантов нет.

Здесь действует **пространственный** принцип: справочник представляется в виде **объемного** предмета, из которого мы извлекаем информацию.

Но если это будет **плоский (или обобщенный)** предмет, то используется предлог С: информация с видеокамер, с датчиков, с экрана телевизора, с сайта, с форума и т. д.

**Примечание**. Просторечный вариант *мы с Рязани*  также объясняется разным подходом в предложном управлении: из Рязани (город мыслится как объемное/организованное пространство), а с Рязани — как бы с рязанских земель.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon!

Comment: Вот я и не хотел делать акцент на "извлечении информации". А на источнике. По аналогии с *ветер с той стороны — информация "пришла" со справочника*.

Comment: oleedd, я бы не советовала вам (никогда и нигде) использовать это выражение (информация со справочника), даже если вы списали телефон с его обложки. Иначе люди  точно подумают, что вы с Рязани или еще что-нибудь похуже, а вам это нужно?  (Вариант Alex_ander вас не спасет). Можете в каком-то конкретном случае сказать так: информация с обложки справочника.

Comment: Сайт тоже объёмный (в плане информации). И из него тоже вполне можно извлекать информацию. Имелось в виду: со справочника Грамоты, который является сайтом. Так что тут некий гибрид — можно выбирать.

Comment: Иметь в виду вы можете всё что угодно - к правилам грамматики это не относится. Тогда пишите так: информация с сайта Грамоты.ру, на котором расположен Справочник. Длинно, конечно, зато правильно. Но лучше сказать так: информация из справочника. Согласны?

Comment: Мне больше "со" нравится. Разговорный язык повсюду, а литературный - только в изысканной литературе.

Comment: Надо различать: разговорный язык, просторечие, ненормированный вариант.  Ваш номер третий, близкий ко второму.

Answer (score 1):

Такое возможно лишь в редких, экзотических случаях. Если **на** обложке попавшегося под руку телефонного справочника или на оставленной **на** нём (сверху, в закрытом состоянии тома) бумажке набросать схему сигнализации, то информация оказывается нанесённой или положенной **на** справочник или в условном смысле "хранится **на** справочнике". Злоумышленники могут воспользоваться такой "информацией **со справочника**", скопировав её **со справочника**, - вопреки обычным случаям, когда нужно заглядывать **в** справочник (*внутрь* него) и извлекать информацию **из** него.

Comment: Да, верно) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Тут не играет роли, кто что думает о том, как это звучит официально или заумно... Это нормы языка, а не личные предпочтения. Просто человек малочитающий, который вырос в среде, где употребляют такие «корявости», будет воспринимать нормальный грамотный язык как нечто с претензией на... Совершенная норма говорить и писать «из справочника». А выражение «со справочника» могут употреблять лишь люди из малообразованной среды. Те, кому вероятно покажется странным вместо «ихние» и «евоные» использовать «их» и «его».
Есть понятия грамотно и безграмотно — другого отношения к языку не дано.

Comment: Оleedd, считаете, из малообразованной среды? Изысканно ведёте дискуссию, громко. Восклицательного знака в конце очень не достаёт.